# Simplify $(1\, 2)(3\, 4)(1\, 3)(2\, 4)$ into composite of two transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

What I did was writing  $(1\, 2)(3\, 4)(1\, 3)(2\, 4)$ as $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1& 2 &3  & 4\\ 
 2& 1 &4  & 3
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1& 2 &3  &4 \\ 
 3&  4& 1 & 2
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ which is equal to $(1 4)(2 3)$

Is what I'm doing right ? And isn't there any other method for it ?

Comment: To check, I would do the products differently. We have $(34)(13) = (341)$ and $(12)(341) = (1234)$ and finally $(1234)(12) = (1)(234)$. Not sure which is right...

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct.

Alternatively, you could make use of the fact that disjoint cycles commute and, instead, compute $(34)(12)(24)(13)$. This makes little if any difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is what I'm doing right ?

Yes.

> And isn't there any other method for it ?

Yes, in particular you can skip the matrix notation. Assume your permutation acts from left, so you can write it as $\sigma=\sigma_4\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1$, where the indexes denote what factor acts first. Now, let's follow the story of $1$: what's the first factor doing something on ("moving") $1$? $\sigma_2$, which sends $1$ to $3$; then, $\sigma_3$ sends $3$ to $4$, and finally $\sigma_4$ does nothing on ("fixes") $4$. So, for the time being, $\sigma=(14)\dots$. Now, follow likewise yourself the story of $2$.